# Racket - how to get the “previous executed command” in bash script?

Tags: racket

Is there any keyboard which echoes to the screen the "previously executed command"? Something like the up-arrow key at Linux bash...

It's not duplicate to [How do I get "previous executed command" in a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756360/how-do-i-get-previous-executed-command-in-a-bash-script)

Comment: I'm looking for something with keyboard ..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Load [XREPL](http://docs.racket-lang.org/xrepl/index.html) and you'll get readline-style input editing, which should include the ability to load previous lines using the up-arrow key.

```
(require xrepl)
```